# Android Emulator Issue - HAX kernel module is not installed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run an Android Emulator on i5-3220 8GB RAM computer, but I get the following error -

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
enter code here CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

[image]

I have made sure that virtulization is enabled on the system as shown in the image below -

[image]

I searched other post for solutions where they pointed disabling Hyper-V is the solution to this problem. But I was unable to find hyper-v in the Windows feature manager -

[image]

How can I possibly proceed to get an android emulator running?

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps... heres [Intel documentation for HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)